# How to get th (header) text from a table using Jquery, when header is a {{ variable }}

Tags: jquery, html, flask, datatables

i've seen a bunch of posts about getting the value/text from a header, but none of the solutions work on my specific use-case, and i'm suspecting that it might be due to my header getting its value from my underlying python-code (i'm using flask).

```
<table id="UCNTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[0] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[2] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[3] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[4] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[5] }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for row in data %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    {{row.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    {{row.Amt}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    {{row.OK}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    {{row.Err}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    {{row.prT}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[0] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[2] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[3] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[4] }}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    {{ header[5] }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

   <script>
        $('#UCNTable tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        } );
</script>
```

So basically, this should say "search *variable*", but it just says search.
Any ideas of what i am doing wrong?
I'm suspecting that JQuery is looking for some text, but it has a problem since it's a variable - any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the **output** html of your flask code?

Comment: @Mosh Feu Uhh, yeah sure! is a picture ok? https://i.imgur.com/FJ9wUJO.png
If i remove the *.text()* from the title variable it will say "Search [object Object]

Comment: output **html** :) so we could try to debug it.

Comment: @Mosh Feu Sorry, i'm not a web developer, so i'm not sure exactly what that entails! is output html what i can get by inspecting (CTRL+SHIFT+I) on my page?

Comment: @Mosh Feu (I can't edit my comment, so i'm writing again) It seems that a rogue newline has somehow come between search and *variable*
`<input type="text" placeholder="Search 
     ERRORProducts
     ">`

Comment: Great, happy to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix!
It turns out, that in my function, when the *variable* was added to the placeholder, somehow a rogue /n newline appeared in there, so i trimmed the variable to have it show the result properly

```
$('#UCNTable tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();         
        var trimTitle = $.trim(title.replace(/[\t\n]+/g,' '));

        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+trimTitle+'"/>' );
    } );
```